# Вопросы по поводу функции загрузки файла на winAPI

Tags: winapi, filestream

У меня есть програма WinAPI которая загружает файл и выводит  в окно  содержания файла. Но я  так  подумала, а мне  ж нужно выводить сообщения когда я  не смогла загрузить файл, или нажала  отмена  чистить  предыдущий вывод(у меня   остается  от прежнего). Но я  не  знаю как  это  делать. В документации  не смогла  найти. Можете скинуть  примеры чтобы я смогла  сделать. Буду  благодарна. Код свой не скидываю так как  нету кода по тому что меня интересует.

Comment: Ну... если совсем туго вывести воспользуйтесь [МеssageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) . Его можно и с красным крестиком нарисовать.

Comment: @nick_n_a, та нет самое сообщение что не  загрузился файл через МеssageBox  я выведу. Вопрос в  другом.  как узнать что я  нажала кансел. я  то  знаю, но как в  код это передать?

Comment: Всё зависит от того чем открываете. Если есть исключение - его можно поймать try-catch.

Comment: Если это OpenFile и т п. - он вернёт результат <=0. Read - вернёт что прочитано 0 байт и т д.

Comment: @nick_n_a if (GetOpenFileName(&file) == FALSE)
так  можна? И меня именно нажатия кнопки кансел интересует.

Comment: Да, вполне. Можна.

Comment: Если не нужно проверять "заблокирован ли файл для чтения/записи" - то этого достаточно. Если нет - нужно проверять что вернёт OpenFile .

Comment: @nick_n_a тоесть GetOpenFileName(&file) == FALSE при нажатии кансел сработает ж? не  нужно проверять

Comment: Да. Сработает точно.

Comment: @nick_n_a ок я попробую . если че. напишу  снова) спасибо за инфу

Comment: [GetOpenFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646927(v=vs.85).aspx) Пользуйтесь MSDN.

Comment: @nick_n_a о еще вопрос. а как  обнулять все при отмене?

Comment: можно сделать return наверно. Не понятно что значит "обнулять". Можно поставить `{ а=0;}` и там присвоить нули тому что нужно обнулить.

Comment: @ у меня есть hEdit куда я вывожу  результат. так  этот едит нужно очистить. clear сделать когда я  не смог загрузить файл